# How to parse specific number from mySQL text fields

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table column with a bunch of text in each field.  There is a specific sentence within each field that remains consistent (except for the actual price) that states:

"The price is $15,350."

I would like to parse out the dollar figure from each field and put it into its own column.

What is the SQL statement to make this happen?

Comment: So, you mean you want '15350'?

Comment: if the string is consistent, you can simply operate with locate() and substr().

Comment: yeah, I want 15350 as the output.  I should clarify that there is variable text before and after the text "The price is $____."

Comment: @Gregg: Please see my latest edit to the answer and check out the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0513/11

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select replace(replace(mid("The price is $15,350.", 15), ",", ""), ".", "");
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| replace(replace(mid("The price is $15,350.", 15), ",", ""), ".", "") |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 15350                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (also check out the [SQL Fiddle of the solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0513/11))

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(
    SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING( myval,
      LOCATE('The price is $', myval) + 15,
      LENGTH(myval) - LOCATE('The price is $', myval)
    ), 1,
      LOCATE('.',
        SUBSTRING( myval,
          LOCATE('The price is $', myval) + 15,
          LENGTH(myval) - LOCATE('The price is $', myval))
       ) 
    ), ',', '') as Result

FROM tbl
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (kept since it covers some basic parsing concepts and also informs the last-submitted solution):

If things are that consistent then a simple series of `REPLACE` functions to remove text *around* the original value with an empty strings should do it. Example:

```
SELECT your_column AS original_value,
REPLACE(REPLACE(your_column, 'The price is $', ''), '$', '') AS parsed_value
FROM your_table
```

OUTPUT:

```
original_value           parsed_value
The price is $15,350.    15,350.
```

You could wrap an additional REPLACE call to remove the comma ',' like this:

```
SELECT your_column AS original_value,
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(your_column, 
            'The price is $', ''), '$', ''), ',', '') AS parsed_value
FROM your_table
```

NEW OUTPUT:

```
original_value           parsed_value
The price is $15,350.    15350.
```

**EDIT - Addressing additional text around "The price is..." block:**

```
SELECT your_column AS original_value,
SUBSTRING('The price is $',
    LOCATE ('The price is $', your_column)
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(your_column, 
            'The price is $', ''), '$', ''), ',', '')
,
```

AS parsed_value
    FROM your_table

The resulting value, 15350., should now easily cast to a decimal with an additional `CAST(xxxxx AS DECIMAL(10,2))` wrapped around the result.

Comment: Paul, I should have clarified that there is text before and after "The price is $___."  I just tried your code and it worked except that all the text before and after is still there.  I was just wanting to parse that price out and leave everything behind.  Is there an edit to this code that will make that happen?  Also, thank you

Comment: @Gregg: Hmmm. Is that text consistent as well or is it just `The price is $___.` ?

Comment: the only consistent part is The price is $____.

Comment: OK. See my updated answer. You also play with the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0513/11